# RxJS skip debounce when using startWith

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a stream that uses the `startWith` operator and `debounceTime`. I want the first value to skip the debounceTime and start immediately. How can I do it?

```
control.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(control.value), <=== this needs to skip debounce
      debounceTime(200),
      map(...),
    );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just switch the order of operators and use `startWith` after `debounceTime`.

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  startWith(control.value),
  map(...),
);
```

Comment: The order of operators matters. When you subscribe at the end of the chain the internal subscriptions between operators are created bottom-up. So when a subscription to `startWith` is created it immediately emits `control.value` before subscribing to the operator above it.

Comment: @martin very important addition. Might I suggest you edit it into your answer? :-)